# JenkinsFile buildWithParameters URL, where is my property?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

I have been working with JenkinsFile pipeline as code for a while, but yet to find a solution for the following case.

We trigger build, from a GIT repo, the URL contains parameters like this:

http://localhost:8080/job/Pipeline-Pull-Request-Composer/buildWithParameters?token=secret_token&git_ref_change=${PULL_REQUEST_FROM_ID}&pull_request_url=${PULL_REQUEST_URL}

Now, my question is that the parameters are not available in the pipeline, unless I define a job parameter with the same name.

How can I configure the pipeline to read the parameter from the URL in an jenkins env variable/property ?

Thank You

Comment: Which version of Jenkins are you using?

Comment: We use 1.6x with the jenkins pipeline plugins. Do you imply a newer version has a solution for this?